# Too much data with var_dump in symfony2 doctrine2

Tags: php, debugging, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I have around 40 entities and many bidirectional relationships.
Whenever i use var_dump($user) or any entity my browser gets loaded with too much data of arrays and variables then it just crashed.

i want to whats the problem.

The data is being inserted fine. Can i cause issue in production.

Comment: What browser are we talking about?

Comment: Are you using xdebug? If not, consider to use it and instead of var_dump just make use of the step debugger with a IDE like Ecplipse, Netbeans or PHPStorm. All these will display the variables data nicely.

Comment: What do you mean by "crashing" - does the browser application (or tab) close, or it display no result, or the page is interrupted?

Comment: my browser displays very long page of variables data with all my entiies and all that. looks like it goes in never ending loop. i tried botf firefox and chrome. if i try any other class whic has no relation then it works ok but with many relationships it freezez the computer. i had to end task that

Comment: I have a bare-bones class and my browser crashed too. I'm hating all these retarded defaults.

Comment: This is also relevant for ZF2!

Comment: xdebug is definitely what you need, yes!

Answer (score 233, accepted):

Replace **var_dump()** with the debug method **[dump()](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/latest/Doctrine/Common/Util/Debug.html)** provided by [Doctrine Common](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/latest/Doctrine/Common.html).

```
\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($user);
```

It works for single objects and Doctrine collections and should prevent browser displaying issues you are having.

Comment: You can also `dump()` with **MaxDepth**, in `dump()` second argument is **MaxDepth**.

Comment: If you prefer to have the debug output in your php error log, use the following: `error_log(print_r(\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::export($variable, $depth),1));`

It's pretty cumbersome to type every time, but you can easily create a macro for it.

Comment: This function is very helpful! Saved me from browser crashes as well.

Comment: This class is deprecated - you should use the [Symfony var dumper](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html) instead

Answer (score 21):

well formatted :

```
echo '<pre>';
\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($user, $recurciveLevelToDisplay);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple and easy example.

```
var_dump(serialize($Object));
```

Answer (score 5):

**Symfony < 2.6**

You can use `\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($variable, $depth);` it displays doctrine output without the proxy information.

**Symfony > 2.6**

If you are using symfony 2.6 or more, I strongly advice you to use `dump()`.
It shows a well formated and colored output, and you can dynamically expend/hide rows.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that in a bidirectional relationship both entities have a link to each other, so while displaying entity1 var_dump will also have to print all properties of entity2, which include entity1 itself giving you a loop.

Comment: This is the only answer that explain the WHY it happens.

Answer (score 2):

The get_object_vars() improve the visualization too.

```
echo "<pre>";
\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump(get_object_vars($user));
```

Answer (score 2):

With Symfony 2.6 you can now just use dump($var) in your controller and {{ dump(var) }} in twig.

Make sure to add this to your AppKernal.php file, in the array('dev', 'test') section.

```
$bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
```

Answer (score 2):

use dump($user) and you can see perfect result in Symfony Profiler! good luck

Answer (score 1):

Just use
echo serialize($user);