# Symfony2: Convert retrieved objects to array (and dumping variables for troubleshooting)

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an Entity Category, which is linked to itself in order to form a tree (a category can have a category as a parent and a category can have a bunch of categories as children). These are marked as private inside the Entity and not exposed to the serializer.

When I do `$category->getChildren()->toArray()`, I get an array of the children, but when I do `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepsitory('PmbLicensing:Category')->findByParent($category)->toArray()`, I get an error that `toArray()` is not defined. I need to use the latter because the top level categories have their parent set to null, so I cannot use the former method. How do I convert the collection of categories obtained in the latter method to an array?

Also, when trying to trouble shoot, I often would like to print out variables, but when I do something like `print_r($categories);`, `print_r((array)$categories);` or `var_dump($categories);` the call just runs for about two minutes and then returns null. I assume it is because of the relational mapping that goes into an infinate loop, but how do I stop this from happening?

**Edit:** I want to convert the object (or collection of objects) to an array, because I want to build a recursive function where the children categories of the supplied category can be retrieved up to n-depth. If the supplied category can be null, in order to retrieve from the main level of categories (with parent set to null). Here is my function:

```
private function getRecursiveChildren(Category $category = null, $depth, $iteration)
{   
    $children = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PmbLicensingBundle:Category')->findByParent($category);
    // \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($children); die();
    if ($depth > $iteration)
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $child['children'] = $this->getRecursiveChildren($child, $depth, $iteration+1);
    }
    return $children;
}
```

On the line that has $child['children'], is says that I cannot use an object as an array.

Comment: for the print_r issue I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902099/too-much-data-with-var-dump-in-symfony2-doctrine2 very helpful

Comment: Thank you Syjin, that will help alot with debugging in future. My main problem at the moment is converting the retrieved collection/object into an array with the latter method mentioned, so if anybody has any suggestions regarding that, it would be most appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post your exact error message?

Comment: When adding `->toArray()` at the end of the method or I attempt `$children = $children->toArray()` the error is: "Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object in ...". $children is not empty. The debug dump of $children returns data (too long to post in comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your

```
$children = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PmbLicensingBundle:Category')
                                ->findByParent($category);`
```

already returns an array so you don't have to (and can't) use `->toArray()`.

When you loop through your categories with

```
foreach ($children as $child)
    $child["..."] = ...
```

You are treating an obect `$child` like an array with `["..."]`. That's what your error message is about.

---

If you can, you should probably use doctrine and let it fill the related child and parent categories. See the [Doctrine Documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing) on this. Then you have automatically all your Children and can access them like `$category->getChildren()` (This one will return an ArrayCollection). This will save you a lot of work.

Comment: Thank you. I realized after trial where and what is happening. I updated by recursive algorithm to the following and it works now:

    private function getRecursiveChildren($categoryId, $depth, $iteration)
    {
 $children = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PmbLicensingBundle:Category')->findByParent($categoryId);
 if ($depth > $iteration)
     foreach ($children as $key => $child) {
     $children[$key] = $child->toArray();
     $children[$key]['children'] =   $this->getRecursiveChildren($child->getId(), $depth, $iteration+1);
 }
 return $children;
    }

Answer (score 1):

If you need the results as an array you can return them from the database as arrays.

In your `CategoryRepository` class:

```
public function findArrayByParent($categoryId) 
{ 
    // it's a good adivce from @i.am.michiel to pass only the `id` here. 
    // You don't need the whole category object.

    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('...')
        ->setParameters(array('categoryId' => $categroyId));

    return $query->getArrayResult();
}
```

They are never converted to objects after being retrieved from the DB so you also save time and memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your call simply returns no categories. Btw, I think you should pass the id of the category, not the entity.

```
$this->getDoctrine()
     ->getRepository('PmbLicensing:Category')
     ->findByParent($category->getId());
```

And why use the toArray() function? ArrayCollection already are arrays with a few additionnal methods? You should be able to use an ArrayCollection whenever you used an array.

Comment: I am trying to build a recursive function where it returns the children categories and the children of the children, etc up to an n depth specified. (3 or 5 levels down for instance). I want to convert the returned categories to an array so that I can append their children to each category with a recursive algorithm. When a category is not supplied to this method at inception, the method assumes that it must start from the top level of categories, which has their parent set to null, so I must use the latter method mentioned.