# how to convert object to array Symfony2

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I have an object named Property, how can I convert that to array

```
/**
 * @Route("/property/{id}/pictures/download_all", name="property_zip_files_and_download", methods={"GET"})     
 */
public function zipFilesAndDownloadAction(Property $property)
{
    $pictures = $property->pictures;
$compressPath = $this->get('some_service.property.picture_compress')->compress($pictures);
//some code for download...
....
}
```

How can I convert the pictures to array and pass it to my service? Can anyone please help me out here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2: Convert retrieved objects to array (and dumping variables for troubleshooting)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653870/symfony2-convert-retrieved-objects-to-array-and-dumping-variables-for-troubles)

Answer (score 0):

What is pictures?

In simple cases you can use `(array) $pictures`.

Also, you can use [Serializer Normalizers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#normalizers)

if variable is `Iterator` (ArrayCollection or PersistentCollection for example) and service method has `array` as typehinting, you can convert it to simple array with [iterator_to_array](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.iterator-to-array.php) function.

Try:

```
$compressPath = $this->get('some_service.property.picture_compress')->compress(iterator_to_array($pictures));
```

Comment: If I use `(array) $pictures`  am getting an error in my service

Comment: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object` inside my foreach `$media = $picture->media;`

Comment: What is $pictures? You're can show var_dump() result?

Comment: ` /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="My_Picture", mappedBy="my_property")
     */
    public $pictures;`

Comment: I update my answer. If it not help, show compress method signature.

Comment: Can you plz provide me your Email Id?

Comment: You're can ask me here. Please add more information about "compress" method

Comment: Doctrine relations return iterators. They work as arrays, you're can use it in foreach, use count() etc. Try call var_dump for $pictures, $pictures is *Collection?

Comment: Okay, you can use it as array, foeach be work.

Also, you can convert it to simple array:
$pictures = iterator_to_array($pictures);

Answer (score 0):

This is how I turned my model MyObject object into a data array.

```
class MyObject{

    public function getContentArr($objInstance, $filter=true){

        $arr = array();

        if($objInstance){
            $response = new Response(GeneralFunctions::getKernel()->getContainer()->get('serializer')->serialize($objInstance, 'json'));

            $arr = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);

            //remove all items that are null, or empty string
            //if($filter){
               //$arr = $this->filterContentArr($arr); // optional
            //}
        }        

        return $arr;
    }

    /**
     * Returns filtered array removing empty/null
     * 
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     */
    public function filterContentArr($data){               
        foreach($data as $key => $val){
            if(is_array($val)){

                $data[$key] = $this->filterContentArr($val);

                if(empty($data[$key])){
                    unset($data[$key]); //remove empty array
                }

            }else{
                if($val == "" || $val == null){
                    unset($data[$key]);
                }
            }
        }

        return $data;
    }
}

$myObject = new MyObject();
print_r($myObject->getContentArr($myObject));
```