# Symfony2 search form hanging

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to create a simple search form that uses an entity type to create the form.

```
private function createCreateForm()
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('search_results'))//->add('search', 'search')
            ->add('professions','entity', array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Profession',
                'property'     => 'name',
                'multiple'     => true,
                'expanded' => true))
            ->add('submit', 'submit')
            ->getForm(); 
}
```

This work perfectly and my form has the checkboxes created from my database records.

However, when I try to handle the request on POST - it just hangs and does nothing!

```
public function resultAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createCreateForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $professions = $form->getData();

    print_r($professions);
}
```

All I wanted to retrieve was an array of the select options so I could perform a search query with them.

If I just create an array of values, it works fine which makes me wonder if it is hanging as it attempts to resolve the entity relationship on handleRequest()?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: I should note, when I say hangs; it pretty much freezes my browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Too much data with var\_dump in symfony2 doctrine2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902099/too-much-data-with-var-dump-in-symfony2-doctrine2)

Answer (score 1):

The output data is too big. Try `print_r($professions[0]);` or, if `$professions` is an `ArrayCollection`, `print_r($professions->first());`. You can also use `\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($professions);`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! However if it was to big, would the following work ?        $professions = $form->get('professions')->getData();
        
        print_r($professions);

Comment: I can't even access the post value from the submitted request

Answer (score 1):

As of Symfony 2.6 there is the VarDumper component's dump() function that will work fine with Doctrine objects

see here for more details: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-vardumper-component