# Symfony 2 - fetch the last inserted row from table

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

How can I rewrite this code in order to get last inserted record from the table?

```
$repository = $entityManager->getRepository('AdminBundle:MyTable');
$product = $repository->find($id);
```

I  tried something like

```
$repository->findBy(array('id','DESC')->setMaxResults(1);
```

But it did not work for me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could get the latest record by using `findBy()` with order by, limit and offset parameters

```
$results = $repository->findBy(array(),array('id'=>'DESC'),1,0);
```

- First argument is for filter criteria
- Second argument takes order by criteria
- Third argument  is for limit
- Fourth argument sets offset

Note it will return you the results set as array of objects so you can get single object from result as `$results[0]`

[FindBy() Examples](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions)

Comment: I used your code and get this error: "[Doctrine\ORM\ORMException]                                                           
  Invalid order by orientation specified for Backend\AdminBundle\Entity\MyTable#0"

Comment: @Jacek717 My bad it was key/value pair `'id'=>'DESC'` check the updated answer

Comment: I think that works! I get no errors. But I stil have a problem with fetching data from $results array. I mean when I try to type something like $output->writeln($results[0]); I get error: "PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 0". I'm a little newbie in PHP/Symfony so maybe it's very dummy question but I don't know how I can get info from this variable. Can you help?

Comment: @Jacek717 what do you see if you [dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902099/too-much-data-with-var-dump-in-symfony2-doctrine2)  $results

Comment: Ok I found where was the problem. I change argument for limit from 0 to 1 and now everything works fine. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Slight nuance, you passed 0 as limit and 1 as offset, you rather want to reverse that with `$results = $repository->findBy(array(),array('id'=>'DESC'),1,0);`

Answer (score 11):

Instead of hacking code where you want to use it, you can also create a repository method and call it when necessary.

```
/**
 * Repository method for finding the newest inserted
 * entry inside the database. Will return the latest
 * entry when one is existent, otherwise will return
 * null.
 *
 * @return MyTable|null
 */
public function findLastInserted()
{
    return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder("e")
        ->orderBy("id", "DESC")
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

References:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-the-repository

Comment: Replacing `id` by `e.id` seems to be necessary.

Comment: While the answer provided by @M Khalid Junaid offers simplicity, the one posted by @user3932886 has better reusability and allows your repository/query logic remain in one place, i.e. inside the repository class and therefore should be preferred in most cases.

Answer (score 5):

After looking for one I decided to try it myself, I think it was much less verbose:

```
$myRepository->findOneBy([], ['id' => 'DESC']);
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try the below one

```
$repository = $entityManager->getRepository('AdminBundle:MyTable');
$repository->setMaxResults(1)->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
$results = $repository->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
```

Reference:
https://undebugable.wordpress.com/2016/01/27/symfony2-querybuilder-find-first-and-find-last-record-in-table/

Comment: I used your approach and get this error: "Undefined method 'orderBy'. The method must star with either findBy or findOneBy!"

Answer (score 1):

You can add these functions to your repository:

```
public function getLastRow(): ?YourEntity
{
    return $this->findOneBy([], ['id' => 'DESC']);
}

public function getLastId(): int
{
    $lastRow = $this->getLastRow();
    return $lastRow ? $lastRow->getId() : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can be collected by getting the id of the inserted object

```
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
$entity->getId();
```

OR

```
$entitymanager->getRepository("entity")->findBy([],["id"=>desc])->getId();
```